# Cannot take latitude and longitude from address description in IOS by using geocoding package in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios

I got latitude and longitude in android but not in ios.
I have tried geocoder, flutter_geocoder and location_geocoder packages but they also did not work in ios.
[image: Geocoding method]

Comment: please attach code of `locationFromAddress` method code for understanding your problem in better way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.